# Do you pay gas fees on Open Sea if no one buys your item?

Tags: gas, fees

i know you pay gas fees if you cancel a post but what if the time expires on it? do you have to pay the gas fees when that happens as well?  ( for Open Sea)

Answer (score 1):

no you don't pay any fees when an auction expires.

listing an nft as auction is a `Gas-Free Action` on OpenSea

For more info on OS fees see [here](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/1500006315941-What-are-gas-fees-on-OpenSea-)